# OLMAPI32.dll Access Violation - When using Outlook Redemption via Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, outlook-redemption

Running on Windows 10 with Office 2016

**From VBA (MS Word):**

Reference Redemption.dll

Running the following code will create a session and return the account name

```
    Dim r As New RDOSession

    r.Logon

    Debug.Print r.Accounts.Item(1).Name

    r.Logoff

    Set r = Nothing
```

**From Visual Studio (VS) 2015 VB.NET project:** (same for VS2010 and VS2013)

Reference Redemption.dll

Running the following code ...

```
    Dim sess As New Redemption.RDOSession

    sess.Logon()

    MessageBox.Show(sess.Accounts(1).Name)

    sess.Logoff()
```

...generates this exception when it tries to create the RDOSession object.

> Exception thrown at 0x0F304797 (OLMAPI32.DLL) in RedemptionTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

The event log reports:

> Faulting application name: RedemptionTest.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x587e37c6
>   Faulting module name: olmapi32.dll, version: 16.0.6965.6571, time stamp: 0x58606a5b
>   Exception code: 0xc0000409
>   Fault offset: 0x00134797
>   Faulting process id: 0x4ce0
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d270d888a9b2ff
>   Faulting application path: C:\Redox\Test\RedemptionTest\RedemptionTest\bin\x86\Debug\RedemptionTest.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\olmapi32.dll
>   Report Id: 7c4170c7-b227-4839-b956-3b51c52920c0
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

However, if I create an installation file for the VB project and install it on my machine, it will run the installed application and return the account name without any exceptions.

This used to work fine.  I can't remember if it worked via VS after I installed Office 2016 and it certainly hasn't worked since upgrading to Win 10.

Any suggestions on how I can get it to work via VS?  Many thanks.

Redemption Ver: 5.0

Comment: What version of  Redemption are you using?

Comment: It's a very old version 5.

Comment: Dmitry - After trying all sorts of random things - I didn't list them because I had no idea what I was doing - I thought I need to try the latest redemption version. I forgot and in my frustration with failing with everything else I asked the question.  I have just tested with 5.12 developer version and it works!

Comment: Yep, Outlook 2016 C2R broke the way MAPI system is loaded - you need to have the latest version (5.12, or at least 5.11) to support Outlook 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Dmitry's comment:

> Outlook 2016 C2R broke the way MAPI system is loaded - you need to have the latest version (5.12, or at least 5.11) to support Outlook 2016.

Installing and using Redemption 5.12 solves the issue with running from Visual Studio.

Thanks Dmitry.